# How to add block of editable text to wordpress homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

Bit of a wordpress amateur here.

I am creating a theme. On the home page there will be 2 sections...

1. Latest post excerpt (I know how to do this!)
2. An 'About us' section - paragraph of text which I would like the client to be able to edit in the admin section, so not hard-coded. How can I create the code for this?

I am thinking of creating a page in the admin, then use PHP includes on the home page to display that page, but I don't think this is the best way.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have used the best plugin ever in Wordpress Advance Custom fields plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/screenshots/

Install in your Wordpress site.

Create a group for specific page.

Here you can create a specific block for specific page like home page, About us Page etc from admin side.

AND

Get this value in home page and display it.

Note: Please read the description and see the screen shot of this plugin

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty..

```
<?php
$content = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'page'));
foreach ($content as $post):
    if ($post->ID == 6) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_content();
    }
endforeach;
?>
```

Replace `6` with the ID of your About page. It's not an elegant solution, but it'll do the job.